# How to specify to NOT map an object Property in MongoDB with NORM

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

I have a calculated property in my object that I don't want to save to the DB, is there a way I can specify that?

Like this one as an exemple :

```
public virtual string FullInfos
    {
        get
        {
            var html = Contact1Info;
            html += Contact2Info;
            return html;
        }
    }
```

Where Contact1Info and Contact2Info are automatic property already saved...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoRM provides a series of attributes. In this case you're looking for the `[MongoIgnore]` attribute.

Should be as simple as

```
[MongoIgnore]
public virtual string FullInfos
    {
        get
        {
            var html = Contact1Info;
            html += Contact2Info;
            return html;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is any documentation about NoRM? I was looking on the net but did'nt found anything.

Comment: NoRM code is here, but I'm sure you know that:
http://github.com/atheken/NoRM

The Google Group is here:
http://groups.google.com/group/norm-mongodb

NoRM is still a small-scale project, so I strongly suspect that you'll do best on the mailing list and taking a look at some of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a method, in which case NORM won't map it.

These kinds of "Properties" are better defined as methods anyways.. in the strict OO sense it shouldn't be viewed as a "Property" of the object if it is being calculated.